# how to run the Mozilla browserQuest?

Tags: javascript, html, client

Wish someone will give me a hand. I am a very very newbie web developer(Even i never hear node.js and how to use it?).Now i download the Mozilla opensource game browserQuest from github.After read the README.md under the bin file.I open the node.js and type the command which it says then come some errors

Could someone show me the procedure step by step.Appreciate any relay.

Comment: Can you add to the question the errors displayed

Comment: Finally i give up .May be there is many i have to learn before launch it.However,thank you for your goodness.:)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested in trying out the BrowerQuest code, or getting involved with further development, use this GitHub repo:

https://github.com/browserquest/BrowserQuest

The Mozilla repo has many bugs, and although a useful reference point, is abandoned. :(